# How do I scrape from the web using python's beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, raw-data

For my class we were tasked with scaping raw data and processing it. I want to scrape data from UFC fights from http://statleaders.ufc.com/en/career.

For example in class we used a different website that had weather data information and we used the line

table = bs.find_all("table")

however, for the ufc site that doesn't work so I looked at the source page and it seems like the class is called "results-table" so tried doing

raw_data = []

## Find all the tables in the webpage page that we have just parsed

table= bs.find_all("div", {"class": "results-table"})

for row in table:
line = row.text
raw_data.append(line)

print(raw_data)

but my raw data is empty. How do I scrape this data correctly?

Comment: The rows are in `class="results-table--tr"`

Comment: so do I replace results-table with results-table--tr

Comment: Yes, I think that should work.

Comment: I tried table= bs.find_all("div", {"class": "results-table--tr"}) and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate all rows and use `stripped_strings` to get the texts out and create a `list` of `dicts`, you could also add the type with `.find_previous('h3')`.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://statleaders.ufc.com/en/career").text,"html.parser")

data = []

for e in soup.select('article .results-table div ~ div'):
    d = dict(zip(['rank','name','total'],list(e.stripped_strings)))
    d['type'] = e.find_previous('h3').text
    data.append(d)

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'rank': '1', 'name': 'Jim Miller', 'total': '41', 'type': 'Total Fights'},
 {'rank': '2',
  'name': 'Andrei Arlovski',
  'total': '39',
  'type': 'Total Fights'},
 {'rank': '3',
  'name': 'Donald Cerrone',
  'total': '38',
  'type': 'Total Fights'},
 {'rank': '4', 'name': 'Clay Guida', 'total': '34', 'type': 'Total Fights'},
 {'rank': '4',
  'name': 'Jeremy Stephens',
  'total': '34',
  'type': 'Total Fights'},
 {'rank': '6', 'name': 'Demian Maia', 'total': '33', 'type': 'Total Fights'},...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided works, but I think you didn't get the data correctly, here's an example of how I did it:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://statleaders.ufc.com/en/career")

bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")

raw_data = []

table = bs.find_all("div", {"class": "results-table--tr"})

for row in table:
    line = row.find_all("span")
    rank = line[0].text
    if rank == "Rnk":
        continue
    name = line[1].find_all("a")[0].text
    total = line[2].text
    print(rank,name,total)
```

Comment: Oh awesome thank you. If I wanted to extract all the data from all the cateogories like total fights, wins, ect. then print it using pandas how would I do that?